# Mostrar dados do banco mysql em uma pagina php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estou com um problema ao mostrar dados de uma tabela do banco na tela.

1. Consegui fazer mostrar os dados porém não consigo pular a linha, mostra os dados sequencialmente, código abaixo.

```
    $sql = $connection->query("Select * from  usuarios");
            if($sql)
           {
                while($exibe = $sql->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        foreach($exibe as $key => $value)
                            {
                                echo "<td>". $value."</td>";
                            }
                    }
            }
```

[image: Imagem de como fica]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
$sql = $connection->query("Select * from  usuarios");
        if($sql)
       {
            while($exibe = $sql->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "<tr>"
                    foreach($exibe as $key => $value)
                        {
                            echo "<td>". $value."</td>";
                        }
                     echo "</tr>"
                }
        }
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeuuu.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique marque como resposta por favor